# What does the phrase "be kept in check" mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In case you will be confused about the context, I put it up as well. Here is the paragraph:

> The cooling increases the ice cover, which increases the surface albedo, so the climate gets even colder, causing more ice to form and so on. This is called the ice albedo feedback. Normally the process **is kept in check** by the ocean's absorption of solar radiation, but according to the Snowball Earth hypothesis, the feedback loop didn't stop.

Does the phrase "is kept in check" mean being restricted or being continually scrutinized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keep/hold%20in%20check):

> **Keep/hold in check**  idiom
>   : to keep (something) under control
>   // He's trying to *hold* his emotions *in check*.
>   // The government has lowered interest rates in an attempt to *keep* inflation *in check*.

To paraphrase the original text:

> Normally the process is kept *[under control]* by the ocean's absorption of solar radiation.

---

While a *person* keeping something *in check* can be "continually [scrutinizing]" it, that scrutinizing is done by them for the *purpose* of not letting it get out of control.

In this case, *the ocean's absorption of solar radiation* is not a person, and it can't scrutinize anything.

However, just as a secondary drain in a bathtub helps prevent water from spilling over the side once the bathtub is filled above a certain level (the secondary drain helps keeps the water level *in check*), so to does the ocean's absorption of solar radiation help keep the formation of ice from becoming excessive.

What the article is saying is that, in this case, there wasn't enough absorption of solar radiation by the ocean to prevent ice formation ("ice albedo feedback") from continuing beyond normal levels.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, the meaning is quite straight-forward: **it is controlled**. Or, to use your own word, "scrutinized" - although "scrutinize" is rather a passive activity, just observation, while "control" is active.

Another way to see it is:

> Normally the process is **balanced** by the ocean's absorption of solar radiation...

Answer (score 0):

"Keep in check" suggests a process of *equilibrium*, in which one force is balanced by another that *limits* it in some way.  For example, this description of a [craft beer variety](https://www.olrepublicbrewery.com/british-ales):

> This light sparkler is fermented in the colder range for the style, which retains the stone fruit aromas while amplifying clean floral notes. The unusually high amount of rye for the style is **kept in check** through careful mash-in temperature control.

In this case the description suggests the rye would otherwise overwhelm the flavor, if it was not *limited* by the temperature control during the brewing process.

"Scrutinize" is not really a synonym for "keep in check" except as part of a larger control process.  For example this photo and its caption:

> [image]
>   *Two prospective yardbirds are **kept in check** by a downtown police officer*  ([source](https://www.wallpaper.com/art/los-angeles-crime-photography-1920-1950))

Yes, the two suspects are being *watched carefully* by the officer, but it's the potential for *force* that keeps them subdued.  Moreover, in order for something to be *scrutinized* you need a conscious observer, who does not exist in your example.